# How to randomize game aobject such as subway coins in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to randomize game aobject such as subway coins in unity

```
void Start () {
    game_over.text="Game Over";
    Ethan = GameObject.Find ("Ethan");
    coin = GameObject.Find ("coin");
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(15, 500), 0, Random.Range(10, 50));

    for (int i=0; i< Random.Range(10,555); i++) {
        Instantiate (coin, position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a questions here?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I think this is some kind of tutorial? I can't see a question here.

Comment: you cannot put this expression "Random.Range(10,555)" INSIDE a foreach.  you must say howMany=Random.Range(10,555) and THEN use that "howMany" inside the comparison.

Comment: hey guys, no need to make smarty comments, particularly if you are new users yourselves.  don't forget, most of the world does not speak English natively, which to begin with can make life hard for a new OP.  (this sentence "Is there a questions here?" actually has a severe grammar error.)  if a question is weak, just click to close. or simply offer the OP direct advice in a couple words ("you did not state your question" or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of any for loop needs to be an integer since you can't loop through something a fraction of a time. I'd do something like this:

```
int iterations = Random.Range(10,555);

print ("iterations = " + iterations);// this will show you what random integer was chosen

for (int i=0; i< iterations; i++) {
    Instantiate (coin, position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```